# Postgres - Force commit to idle transaction

Tags: database, postgresql

I know it is possible to kill Postgres idle transaction, however is it possible to force it to commit.  The commit needs to come from some kind of an agent that monitors idle transactions and not from the module that started the transaction.

Thanks
Avi

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this, and that's a good thing too. How could you be certain that the transaction's work is done and the database is in a consistent state afterwards?

The correct solution is to fix the application so that it does not leave transactions “hanging”.